# PHP Socket Blocking

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

Basically, I'm using a **blocking** TCP socket along with `socket_accept()`. The problem I have, is that for obvious reasons since the I/O is blocking there can only be one connection to the socket at any one time that PHP is able to manipulate. I am fine with this, as this is the behaviour I am after.

However, if a client is to open a connection to the my PHP server, if they are simply leaving the socket open and sending no data, the socket and daemon are rendered useless as the blocking I/O will not allow new requests.

Is there a way to detect a client that is simply sending no data (like a no-transmission timeout) or something similar? I'd rather not use non-blocking I/O.

Comment: Please show your main loop - mostly the call that you are blocking on. (e.g. `$str = fgets($sock);`)

Comment: This is missing the rest of my code as it's very extensive, but that's where socket_read is being used. It's worth noting that the socket is also closed within that loop with socket_close.

Comment: What kind of data is being exchanged? Is it binary or text? If text, is it new line terminated?

Comment: I'm using PHP_BINARY_READ (default), the traffic is just HTTP requests.

Comment: OK so what you are actually writing here is a HTTP server that will accept and process one request at a time? What type of requests will you be accepting, just GET or requests that may have a body as well, like POST/PUT?

Comment: GET and POST, this HTTP server is part of a 'middle man' daemon that intercepts requests from a screenshot application I use personally, to store them on my own server. The POST requests will contain files for upload.

Comment: Are you particularly attached to using PHP for this? It sounds like a prime Node.js use case...

Comment: I've actually already got this exact thing written in Node.js :P. The challenge was to rewrite it in PHP though, so yeah.

Comment: OK give me a few minutes to find some code I did for this sort of thing a while ago and refresh myself on how it worked...

Comment: I seem to have lost the code that I wrote for this, I suspect it is somewhere on an old machine. I will have a look when I get home and stick it verbatim on pastebin if I can find it so you can have a play around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call [the equivalent of](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php#100676) [`stream_set_timeout`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php) to make the blocking reads and writes terminate after a certain timeout:

```
$s = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if (!socket_bind($s, '127.0.0.1', 0)) die("bind failed");
if (!socket_listen($s)) die("listen failed");
socket_getsockname($s, $localA, $localPort);
echo 'Listening on ' . $localA . ': ' . $localPort . "\n";

$c = socket_accept($s);

// Warning: Ugly hack ahead.
// This just mitigates the problem somewhat, and doesn't actually solve it
socket_set_option($c, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec'=>2,'usec'=>0));
socket_set_option($c, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec'=>2,'usec'=>0));

$r = socket_read($c, 1024);
echo 'read finished: got ' . var_export($r, true) . "\n";
```

Note that this is a hack; a malicious attacker can still send only 1 byte per second or so.

Instead of investing time in these crazy hacks, you should really switch to non-blocking IO or handle the accepted sockets in a separate thread/process.

Comment: Would sending one byte cause socket_read() to fire? Or would it still sit there continuing to wait for the end of the data?

Comment: no, `socket_read` will fire fine. But your application will probably keep reading. Unless you're building a throwaway script, I strongly suggest to use proper non-blocking sockets and [`socket_select`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php)

Answer (score 0):

I used Tudor Barbu Thread class to do some pseudo threading for a Websocket server once...

here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/eda7d47ec4e475af531e